# Is there a way to programmatically determine the Enabled APIs for a Google Apps Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script

For a Google Apps Script that I am working on, I need to enable **Google URL Shortener API** and **Google Drive API**.
The trouble comes when I create a copy of the existing Spreadsheet which has a Script attached to it; (everything working the way I want it but I want a copy.)

Now when I create a copy of the Spreadsheet, its associated Script files also get copied - but what does not seem to be copied over are the enable/disable status of various APIs.
**The new copy seems to take on default permissions and only default APIs seem to be enabled.**

*I would not know if the script has required APIs enabled or not. Only when I try to run it, it would throw up an error and crash.*

I would like to programmatically know this and take action when a copy of the spreadsheet is made.

I have done several searches for this but could not find any relevant results hence asking this question here.

Specifically more annoying is the fact that the URL Shortener API and even Drive API have to be enabled in two steps - which includes logging into Developer Console.

If I distribute this tool then they would be forced to go into Source Code and from the code editor forced to enable the APIs.

Please help.

Comment: You may need to create a stand alone HTML Web App, that asks for the new spreadsheet ID.  Then you'd never need to copy the Apps Script file.  You could create new spreadsheets.  Is this for personal use?  Are you copying the spreadsheets and sending them to other people?

Comment: But Sandy Good, creating a stand alone HTML Web App does not address the API On/Off problem. What I am doing is to develop a tool and make it available to lots of people. A stand alone script is possible and I could make the script available to them - but still the API problem would remain. The problem I am trying to address is - how to know which APIs are ON/OFF and alert the user. Ideally turn the required ones on with user's permission. As it is they just try to run it and only then know this API problem.